MD5 error when uploading Azure blobs asynchronously
I am attempting to upload large numbers of blob files to Azure storage as quickly as possible. I am using this snippet of code to attempt to multi-thread the uploads in batches of 50 to get them uploaded faster:
//ASYNC
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(50);
var tasks = new List<Task>();
await semaphore.WaitAsync();
foreach (var callObj in source.Skip(curBatch * batchSize).Take(batchSize))
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var name = ...;
            blob = blobContainerForCalls.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
            await blob.UploadTextAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

This has been working just fine for the last couple days. Starting today, however, these uploads started generating this error: The MD5 value specified in the request did not match with the MD5 value calculated by the server.
If I change this to just upload each one synchronously, it works fine:
//SYNC
foreach (var callObj in source.Skip(curBatch * batchSize).Take(batchSize))
{
    var name = ...;
    blob = blobContainerForCalls.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
    await blob.UploadTextAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
}

Is there something wrong with my ASYNC code that would cause those MD5 errors?

I don't think the semaphore in your code is serving its intended purpose, since your await semaphore.WaitAsync() is outside of your loop.
You should wait for the loop iteration to acquire a semaphore before adding a new task.
Try making the following updates:
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(50);
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var callObj in source.Skip(curBatch * batchSize).Take(batchSize))
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // Acquire semaphore before starting each task
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var name = ...;
            blob = blobContainerForCalls.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
            await blob.UploadTextAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
            // Release semaphore after task completes
        }
    }));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

If the issue persists, or appears to be intermittent, try reducing the semaphore capacity. 50 concurrent threads could be causing throttling of some sort, depending on the specs of the machine running the code.
